# AVL tree rotation example clarification

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

Now, I am learning AVL tree data structure from a book and here's one example which I have a difficulty to understand:

[image: AVL tree rotation case]

Can anyone explain the process of rotation here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your example but I think it is wrong 
AVL tree is height balanced binary search tree (which is not in your example, AUG should be inserted on right hand side of MAY not left)
anyways in AVL tree LR rotation with an example could be like this,

[image]

for good animation you can see ,
[image]